# How to create HTTP 301 redirect from Stellent (Oracle UCM) script

Tags: http-headers, oracle-ucm, idoc, stellent

Is it possible to send a HTTP response with a permanent redirect from a Stellent (now called Oracle UCM) website? We're using version 7.5.2 with iDoc script.

We can use the iDoc function setHttpHeader() to send the Location HTTP header, but how to send the HTTP response code 301, to signal the permanent redirect to the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is component "IdocScriptRedirect" avialable on meta link for 301 redirect. you can request oracle support to provide you download link.

Comment: [Link to IdocScriptRedirect component](https://bitbucket.org/jhult/oracle-webcenter-content-third-party-components/raw/7cf7e1102a8cb9deef8e55840f1c3c505f225cec/idocscriptredirect.zip)

Answer (score 1):

In Site Studio, if you right click a folder and choose "Select Primary Page" and then choose "Use an external URL" radio button, the page will be redirected as a 301 redirect.

Answer (score 0):

No... that function appends new HTTP headers, and the response code is set prior to that. You'll need a custom IdocScript function to get that behavior.

Comment: Do you have a sample of an IdocScript function that could do this?

Comment: The IdocScriptRedirect component above is one example. The [NewIdocScript component](https://jonathanhult.com/intradoc-api/NewIdocScript/readme.htm) from the [How-To Components](http://bexhuff.com/2011/03/howto-component-samples-for-oracle-ucm-11g) is another example.

Answer (score 0):

The Idoc Script function [setRedirectUrl](https://vedranstanic.wordpress.com/2011/12/10/server-side-redirect-with-idoc/) will do what you need.

Example: `<$setRedirectUrl("some url")$>`